# Javascript - Can indentation on method chaining cause issues with semicolons?

Tags: javascript

From [JSLint.com](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html):

> JavaScript uses a C-like syntax which requires the use of semicolons to delimit certain statements. JavaScript attempts to make those semicolons optional with a semicolon insertion mechanism. This is dangerous because it can mask errors.
>
> Like C, JavaScript has ++ and -- and ( operators which can be prefixes or suffixes. The disambiguation is done by the semicolon.
>
> In JavaScript, a linefeed can be whitespace or it can act as a semicolon. This replaces one ambiguity with another.
>
> JSLint expects that every statement be followed by ; except for for, function, if, switch, try, and while. JSLint does not expect to see unnecessary semicolons or the empty statement.

So a good practice is:

```
var one = 'something';
var two = 'other thing';
```

vs:

```
var one = 'something'
  , two = 'other thing';
```

When it comes to method chaining, [Air BnB's Style Guide - under the Whitespace Section](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#whitespace) suggests using indentation for method chains.

```
// bad
$('#items').find('.selected').highlight().end().find('.open').updateCount();

// good
$('#items')
  .find('.selected')
    .highlight()
    .end()
  .find('.open')
    .updateCount();

// bad
var leds = stage.selectAll('.led').data(data).enter().append('svg:svg').class('led', true)
    .attr('width',  (radius + margin) * 2).append('svg:g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (radius + margin) + ',' + (radius + margin) + ')')
    .call(tron.led);

// good
var leds = stage.selectAll('.led')
    .data(data)
  .enter().append('svg:svg')
    .class('led', true)
    .attr('width',  (radius + margin) * 2)
  .append('svg:g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (radius + margin) + ',' + (radius + margin) + ')')
    .call(tron.led);
```

Can this sort of indentation causes issues when Javascript goes to insert semicolons?

Comment: Off topic, but you probably mean `addClass()` instead of `class()`.

Comment: Yeah, thats actually ripped right off of Air BnB's style guide. Just an example :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Indentation is ignored and the line breaks will be too since a valid statement continues on the following lines that have the chained methods.

JavaScript's automatic semicolon insertion is a little complex, but for the most part is very intuitive.

The issues that people run into is where having operators that can be interpreted as a postfix operator start a line where the previous statement wasn't terminated. None of your code suffers from that issue.

As long as you're not forgetting semicolons in a situation like this:

```
// forgot--v
var a = "b" 

(function() {
    // do some stuff
})();
```

or this:

```
// forgot--v
var a = "b"

[1,2,3].forEach(function(n) {
    // do something
});
```

You'll be fine.

Probably the biggest place to be aware of where having a line break would be after a `return` statement.

```
return
{
    foo: "bar"
}
```

This will give you an `undefined` return value instead of the object.

In particular, I prefer this form of variable declaration:

```
var one = 'something'
  , two = 'other thing';
```

Though I put the `,` below the `v` instead of the `r` (doesn't really matter). It makes it easy to see that you've remembered all the commas when there's a long list of variables. It's perfectly safe WRT semicolon insertion.

Comment: Thorough answer. As to `var` declarations with commas, I've always been taught the reason against that is because it can make debugging hard. Thoughts?

Comment: @JDillon522: I've never heard that and haven't had any trouble debugging. Not sure how it would cause problems. I think it makes it easier since on long lines, you can fail to see a missing comma, whereas at the start of the line you can see it immediately..

Answer (score 0):

No; indentation is not part of JS syntax.

Please do not rely on semicolon indentation.

*(Unrelated, but I don't like indentation like that; I prefer to keep them on the same column. That said, your jQuery example when `end()` is being used it seems like it makes sense, so I may have to reconsider.)*